# How to translate a string in Woocommerce single language website

Tags: woocommerce

I need to translate `__( 'privacy policy', 'woocommerce' )` which can be found in `Woocomerce/includes/wp-template-functions.php`. Full code for this is here

```
$privacy_link    = $privacy_page_id ? '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $privacy_page_id ) ) . '" class="woocommerce-privacy-policy-link" target="_blank">' . __( 'privacy policy', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' : __( 'privacy policy', 'woocommerce' );
```

This is included inside textarea in `Woocommerce->settings->Account and privacy`, looks like a shortcode

```
Ukoliko ste pročitali i razumijeli naša [privacy_policy] molimo Vas da...
```

This is actually translated in Croatian language but I would need to change words slightly, how can I do it? Website is single language and I am not able to translate it with Gettext like I did some other strings

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'privacy policy' :
        $translated_text = __( 'pravila privatnosti', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 200, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Loco Translate plug-in (if you're using WordPress). It allows you to translate a lot of things down to the very detail. You can find the plug-in [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/).

Comment: Without plugins please

Comment: you can convert by using mo and po file create. Please see this link https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/